# Must exact functors send acyclics to acyclics?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homology-cohomology, derived-functors

Let $F:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$ be an exact functor between abelian categories, which are some category of sheaves of abelian groups or sheaves of modules...etc on certain topological spaces/schemes/etc.

1. Must $F$ send acyclic objects to acyclic objects (acyclic with respect to the global sections functor)?
2. If $\mathcal{A}$ has enough injectives, must $F$ send injective objects to acyclic objects?
3. Are there reasonable criteria on $F,\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ so that something like (1) or (2) is true?

Comment: What do you mean by "acyclic object"?  Usually we talk about acyclic objects with respect to some particular half-exact functor.

Comment: An example from geometry: Take the functor to be derived the global sections functor and $F=f^{*}$ with $f: X \to \operatorname{spec} k$ smooth. Every sheaf on the right hand side is acyclic and even injective..

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah, that's a great point. I suppose the examples I had in mind had to do with the situation where the categories are abelian categories of sheaves on various spaces. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: My comment applies in this situation. The answer for the $(3)$ is: Whenever the exact functor behaves well with the global sections functor. This is for example the case with $f_*$ when $f$ is a closed immersion or if $f is an affine map of schemes.

Comment: @MooS I suppose the question is - what does it mean to "behave well" (wrt the global section functor)

Comment: I thought this was clear: The global sections of $FA$ and $A$ should be the same.

Comment: You should also think of the functor "Tensoring with a line bundle" to see how wrong $(1)$ is. This brings me to a sufficient condition for $(2)$ to be true: If F is right adjoint to an exact functor.

Comment: @MooS Okay so suppose for all $A$, the global sections of $FA$ are the same as those of $A$. How would you use this to prove that $FA$ is acyclic whenever $A$ is? (I'm sure this is true, but, being a novice at this, I would appreciate a proof).

Comment: I think I forgot to mention, that you also need $F$ to preserve Injectives :( Then you can either show it by hand, taking an injective resolution and or you can invoke the Grothendieck Spectral Sequence.

Comment: @MooS Well my question from the very beginning was basically (a generalization of) "when does $f$ preserve injectives"...

Comment: With the answer: If it is right adjoint to an exact functor. The main examples in the sheaf case: push forward (right adjoint to inverse image), restriction to open subset (right adjoint to extension by zero) and tensoring with a line bundle (inverse to tensoring with the inverse like bundle)

Comment: @MooS I don't understand how to parse your last comment. What exactly is the statement you're making?

Comment: I told you which functors preserve injective. You posed a very vague question and seem to expect a very precise answer. This will not work. I told you that 1. and 2. are false and gave you some sufficient conditions and examples for 3. If you expect more; you should be more concrete and ask another question.

Comment: @MooS You told me which functors preserve injectives? I must have misunderstood something - can you say again which functors preserve injectives? Do you mean that "any functor which is right adjoint to an exact functor must preserve injectives"?

Comment: Yes. For the proof, you just take $Hom(-,FJ)$ with $J$ injective and use the adjunction.